# Can I share a variable between machines using C#?

Tags: c#, windows

I have a C# application running in machine_1 (local PC). This application writes values to a Global Variable. I just want to read the value of the Global Variable using another C# application which is running in a different machine (machine_2) connected with the machine_1 through a network. Is this possible in C#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: almost sound like the good old [remoting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973857.aspx) ... I don't know if you want to use this ... better look for things like message-queues or use something like a file-share, database (I boldly claim that most will do)

Comment: thanks @Carsten for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

No, not a variable as such - not with a regular CLR. (It would be possible to write a VM which *did* share variables across the network, but it would be quite unusual.)

Instead, you'll need to establish some sort of protocol between the two machines so that one can read the current state. (Or store the state in a third machine, e.g. in a database of some kind.)

Answer (score 1):

There are no such things as global variables in C#, everything is bound to a class. Therefor you need an instance of this class to access any member within it or if the member is static the class-name itself.

However since you´re on different machines you cannot access any of them as they run on different VMs also. Write some kind of persisted data (e.g. a web-serice or a simple file within your netweork) to share between the machines.

Comment: _"since you´re on different machines you cannot access any of them"_ - Incorrect. .NET Remoting allows different processes, optionally across the network, to access the same object derived from `MarshalByRefObject`

Comment: @MickyDuncan Oh, did not know this, thanks for pointing this out.